# Toggle DIVs in Bootstrap 3

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to do a small adjustments in this code:

**HTML**

```
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
  <button type="button" title="left" class="btn btn-info active">left</button>
  <button type="button" title="right" class="btn btn-info">right</button>
</div>
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
  <button type="button" title="a" class="btn btn-info">dont toggle</button>
  <button type="button" title="b" class="btn btn-info">another function</button>
</div>
<div id="left"> LEFT CONTENT </div>
<div id="right"> RIGHT CONTENT </div>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
$('.btn-group button').click(function(){
    var ix = $(this).index();

    $('#left').toggle( ix === 0 );
    $('#right').toggle( ix === 1 );
});
```

**CSS**

```
#right { display:none; }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Nz964/

- the 'active' button isn't work. what should I do to toggle the 'active' between the two buttons?
- the javascript code is firing all the buttons in the page, should be just the two buttons

Any help will be great. Thanks.

Comment: Use a [Checkbox Button Group](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#buttons)

Comment: Thx @wumm, I tried this before, but I have a title in the buttons, and using this way, the title do not show up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1st Problem, you are using a very old version of jQuery(1.5) - bootstrap makes use of .on() method which was added in version jQuery 1.7 so You need to upgrade jQuery to 1.7 or above version

2nd problem, you need to narrow down your selector my adding another class

```
<div class="btn-group mytoggle" data-toggle="buttons">
    <button type="button" title="left" class="btn btn-info active">left</button>
    <button type="button" title="right" class="btn btn-info">right</button>
</div>
```

then

```
$('.mytoggle button').click(function(){
    var ix = $(this).index();

    $('#left').toggle( ix === 0 );
    $('#right').toggle( ix === 1 );
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/KYzeb/)